# Golang reading from a file - is it safe from locking?

Tags: go

I have a function that will be called on every single HTTP GET request. The function reads a file, does some stuff to the contents of that file, and returns a slice of bytes of those contents. That slice of bytes of then written as the response body to the HTTP response writer.

Do I need to use a mutex for any of the steps in this function to prevent locking in the event of multiple HTTP requests trying to read the same file? And if so, would a simple RWMutex locking the reading of the file suffice, since I am not actually writing to it but am creating a copy of its contents?

Here is the function:

```
// prepareIndex will grab index.html and add a nonce to the script tags for the CSP header compliance.
func prepareIndex(nonce string) []byte {
    // Load index.html.
    file, err := os.Open("./client/dist/index.html")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // Convert to goquery document.
    doc, err := goquery.NewDocumentFromReader(file)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    // Find all script tags and set nonce.
    doc.Find("body > script").SetAttr("nonce", nonce)

    // Grab the HTML string.
    html, err := doc.Html()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    return []byte(html)
}
```

I also thought about just loading the file once when main starts, but I was having a problem where only the first request could see the data and the subsequent requests saw nothing. Probably an error in the way I was reading the file. But I actually prefer my current approach because if there are any changes to `index.html`, I want them to be persisted to the user immediately without having to restart the executable.

Comment: did you check this repo https://github.com/nightlyone/lockfile ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `RWMutex` won't protect you from the file being modified by another program. The best option here would be to load your file in a `[]byte` at startup, and instantiate `"bytes".Buffer` whenever you use `goquery.NewDocumentFromReader`. In order for the changes to be propagated to the user, you can use fsnotify[1] to detect changes to your file, and update your cached file (`[]byte`) when necessary (you will need `RWMutex` for that operation).

For example:

```
type CachedFile struct {
    sync.RWMutex
    FileName string
    Content  []byte
    watcher  *fsnotify.Watcher
}

func (c *CachedFile) Buffer() *bytes.Buffer {
    c.RLock()
    defer c.RUnlock()
    return bytes.NewBuffer(c.Content)
}

func (c *CachedFile) Load() error {
    c.Lock()
    content, err := ioutil.ReadAll(c.FileName)
    if err != nil {
        c.Unlock()
        return err
    }
    c.Content = content
    c.Unlock()
}

func (c *CachedFile) Watch() error {
    var err error

    c.watcher, err = fsnotify.NewWatcher()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    go func() {
        for ev := range c.watcher.Events {
            if ev.Op != fsnotify.Write {
                continue
            }
            err := c.Load()
            if err != nil {
                log.Printf("loading %q: %s", c.FileName, err)
            }
        }
    }()

    err = c.watcher.Add(c.FileName)
    if err != nil {
        c.watcher.Close()
        return err
    }

    return nil
}

func (c *CachedFile) Close() error {
    return c.watcher.Close()
}
```

[1] https://godoc.org/github.com/fsnotify/fsnotify

Comment: Nice answer! Very well explained. I will test this later today and accept if the concepts work for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you're modifying the file, you need a mutex. `RWMutex` should work fine. It looks like you're just reading it, and in that case you should not see any locking behavior or corruption.

The reason you didn't get any data the second time you read from the same file handle is that you're already at the end of the file when you start reading from it the second time. You need to [seek](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#File.Seek) back to offset `0` if you want to read the contents again.

Comment: Ahh I see now, thanks for the explanation! That makes sense now... and as for the first part, yes, I am not doing any modifications to the file after reading it. A clone of the contents is made, and that clone is what will be modified (but that is safe from locking of course). 

Do I need to close the file after reading?

Comment: Note that the seeking method will be an issue if several goroutines are reading/seeking the file at the same time. I'd suggest loading the file in a `[]byte` at startup, as this would give you performance improvements and you won't need to worry about the file changing on disk.

Moreover, locking the file using a mutex will only protect you from the file being modified by your own program. You will still run into issues if another program modify the file.